# Proving measurability in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am given the problem: suppose for measurable, real-valued functions $f$ and $g$,  and an open set $A \subset \mathbb R ^2$, prove that $\{x \in \mathbb R : (f(x),g(x)) \in A\}$ is a measurable set.

I know that if I could reformulate it such that $\{x \in \mathbb R : (f(x)) \in C\}$, and $\{x \in \mathbb R : (g(x)) \in D\}$, where $C,D$ are open subsets of $\mathbb R$, then it would be a trivial problem, as the definition of measurability says that the inverse image of an open set is measurable.  However, I cannot just do this, and then take the union of $D$ and $C$, because that is obviously not in $\mathbb R^2$.

In other words, how do I get from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$?  I would greatly appreciate any hints, but if possible, please don't give me the full answer to the problem so I can still do some thinking about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it is sufficient to consider sets $A$ of the form $C\times D$, where $C$ and $D$ are open intervals (because these generate the $\sigma$-algebra). For these sets you only have to look at $f^{-1}C\cap g^{-1}D$.